# SQL. Set column Value from a choice of other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Not sure if what I want to do is possible or not, and if it is I've hit a brick wall in my head of how to do it and searching hasn't found the answer.

I have a Column, we'll call it column A. This is currently blank and I want to populate it with the value from either column B or column C (which is randomly chosen).

In essence what I want to do, but which doesn't work is:

update MyTable
set Column A = Column B OR Column C
From  MyTable

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: On what conditions it is taking value from col b or col c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `case`.  If you want random, then:

```
update MyTable
    set Column_A = (case when rand() < 0.5 then Column_B else Column_C end);
```

The above randomly assigns either column for each row.  If you want all `column_A`s to be either from B or C, but randomly chosen, I think I would use a similar technique:

```
update MyTable cross join
       (select @r := rand()) params
    set Column_A = (case when @r < 0.5 then Column_B else Column_C end);
```

Comment: Nice! Just because I am facinated!! What about just selecting from column_B or column_C on a random basis. Feel free to ignore this if its too much effort

Comment: @RiggsFolly - When you say 'random', would you want ALL rows to use the same column, or *(approximately)* 50% to come from B and 50% to come from C?

Comment: @RiggsFolly . . . I don't know what the comment means.  This is randomly assigning from one of those two columns

Comment: Never mind. I was just wondering if instead of creating another column, if it was possible to SELECT either Colum_B or Column_C on a 50/50 basis. And it was just for my own education. I should not have piggy-backed on someone elses question. Sorry

Comment: @RiggsFolly . . . Yes, of course.  Just put the first `case` into a `select`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @GordonLinoff. The second was more the scenario I wanted to achieve, with the randomization being done for each row individually but I'm having issues with getting this to work. What should the cross join joining to? and what is the 'params' bit for? Many thanks!

Comment: @MJ1988 . . . The second uses the same column for *all* rows.  The `cross join` is used to set a variable, and that variable is then used for all rows.

Comment: Thanks for all the help @GordonLinoff, managed to get what I wanted to do! :)